# JQuery Textarea Alphabetizer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple alphabetizer however the problem is it doesn't sort it correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var txt = $(".input-text");
  $(".alphabetize").on("click", function() {
    txt.val(txt.val().split(" ").sort().join(" "));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alphabetizer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
        <a class="alphabetize" href="javascript:void(0)">Alphabetize</a><br />
        <textarea class="input-text" placeholder="Alphabetize your text here...">China
India
United States of America
Indonesia
Brazil
Pakistan
Nigeria
Bangladesh
Russia
Japan
Mexico
Philippines
Ethiopia
Vietnam
Egypt
Germany
Iran
Turkey
Democratic Republic of the Congo
France</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And do you have spaces in that list of countries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the text by new lines (`\n`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var txt = $(".input-text");
  $(".alphabetize").on("click", function() {
    txt.val(txt.val().split("\n").sort().join("\n"));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alphabetizer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
        <a class="alphabetize" href="javascript:void(0)">Alphabetize</a><br />
        <textarea class="input-text" placeholder="Alphabetize your text here...">China
India
United States of America
Indonesia
Brazil
Pakistan
Nigeria
Bangladesh
Russia
Japan
Mexico
Philippines
Ethiopia
Vietnam
Egypt
Germany
Iran
Turkey
Democratic Republic of the Congo
France</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also. While it's not necessary for your example (as all of the lines starts with capital letter), you should know that `.sort()` is case sensitive, so that "*AbCdEf*" will be sorted as "*ACEbdf*".

To make it case insensitive, you can pass a sorting method as argument, where strings `.toLowerCase()` are compared:

```
// ...
txt.val(txt.val().split("\n").sort(caseInsensitive).join("\n"));
// ...

function caseInsensitive(a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: I didn't know sort's case sensitive. Thank you very much bro.